# The HTML <input> element with "capture" attribute is not working in Surface Tablet.

Tags: html

If capture=camera attribute is specified, the camera option to take picture should be displayed. But instead, file upload dialog is displayed. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify accept='image/*' attribute?

Comment: Yes. Still, it opens up a file upload dialog.

Comment: The OS is Window 8. Is that the reason?

Comment: I guess it is the reason, or maybe the browser that cause it happens, try other browsers like Chrome, firfox...

Comment: Is there an alternative for <input capture/> ?